# No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSNumber?' Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

On Xcode 8 and Swift 3 is comes an error by + i have try it anything but come to no result. 
Here the code :

```
static func addNotificationInterval(title: String, body: String,

indentifier: String, interval: Double) {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: title, arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: body, arguments: nil)
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; content.categoryIdentifier = "com.elonchan.localNotification"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: indentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.add(request)

    print("SetNotifiInterval")

}
```

Error comes here by the + :

```
content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; content.categoryIdentifier = "com.elonchan.localNotification"
```

Error Type:

No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSNumber?'

Comment: Please make sure you format your code using CMD-K

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [the latest reference of `UNMutableNotificationContent`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unmutablenotificationcontent):

> `var badge: NSNumber?`
>
> The number to apply to the app’s icon.

In Swift 3, many implicit type conversions, like `Int` to `NSNumber`, are removed. You need to explicitly cast the types between them.

```
content.badge = (UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1) as NSNumber; ...
```

Comment: Thank you it run :)